# can't access validated data or FK relationship within serializer's create() method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I can't seem to access a foreign key value within a serializer's create method. On submitting a POST to create a new instance I receive the following error:

DoesNotExist at /api/v1/organisation/provider/
Service matching query does not exist.

within the traceback is the following:

File "/code/classification/serializers.py" in create
  114.         thisService = Service.objects.get(name=validated_data.get('service'))

the POST data is as follows:
{service: "ServiceProvider1", tenantIdentifier: "9f0e40fe-3d6d-4172-9015-4298684a9ad2", enabled: true}

**My question:**
How can I successfully reference a Service instance based on its name field (not its PK) from the ConnectedService model (FK relationship). error i'm getting is {"service":["Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."]}

**what's I've tried so far based on suggestions below:**

1. attempted to see if I can see validated_data or data from the validate() method. Result was None for both print(validated_data.get('service')) and print(data.get('service'))
2. change the code for the serializer to reference the FK for services. Result for this was **{"service":["Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."]}**

**models.py:**

```
class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('provider name', max_length = 32)
    displayName = models.CharField('provider label display name', max_length = 32)
    helpText = models.TextField('Explanatory text about this provider', max_length = 140, blank=True)
    authzUrl = models.URLField('authorisation URL for service', max_length = 512, blank=True, null=True)
    appID = models.CharField('ID for this app as provided by cloud provider', max_length = 64, blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.displayName

class ConnectedService(models.Model):
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, related_name='connected')
    tenantIdentifier = models.CharField('Tenant identifer for organisation', max_length = 128, null=True, blank=True)
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    organisation = models.ForeignKey('Organisation', blank=True, null=True) #string reference used as a lazy reference for Organisation
```

**serializers.py (updated):**

```
class ConnectedServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = ConnectedService
    fields = ('tenantIdentifier', 'enabled', 'service', 'organisation' )

def validate(self, data):
    #check there is no existing option for this service + organisation combination
    try:
        thisOrganisation = Organisation.objects.get(pk= self.context['request'].user.organisation_id)
        thisService = Service.objects.get(name=validated_data.get('service'))
        thisConnectedService = ConnectedService.objects.get(service=thisService, organisation= thisOrganisation)
        raise serializers.ValidationError('This service is already registered for this organisation')
    except:
        pass
    return data

    def create(self,validated_data):
    thisOrganisation = Organisation.objects.get(pk= self.context['request'].user.organisation_id)
    thisService = Service.objects.get(name=validated_data.get('service'))
    thisConnectedService = ConnectedService()
    thisConnectedService.organisation = thisOrganisation
    thisConnectedService.service = thisService
    thisConnectedService.enabled = True
    thisConnectedService.save()
    return thisConnectedService
```

**views.py**

```
class ConnectedService(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,generics.GenericAPIView, mixins.CreateModelMixin):
    queryset = ConnectedService.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ConnectedServiceSerializer


def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Check with `print(validated_data.get('service'))` if `validated_data.get('service')` contains existing service name. Try `data.get('service')` instead.

Comment: Your `ConnectedService` model has `service` as a foreign key, whereas in your serializer, under `fields` you have `services` as if it were a many to many field. And then in the validate method, you are trying to get `service` from validated data. I'm not sure if validated data will have `service` at all. It may have `services`, but that's probably not what you intended.

Comment: @neverwalkaloner, @slider - I've tried both suggestions. I've changed the serializer and now i'm getting `{"service":["Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."]}` . How can I get the lookup to use "name" attribute and not PK for service lookup?

Comment: Try using a `SlugRelatedField` http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield but also note that if you may want to make the `name` field in your `Service` model unique.

Comment: validated_data within create() seems to be empty. I'm getting a `DoesNotExist` error, which (I think) is because the data is empty. Interestingly, the `validate(self,data)` method also returns None for `data.get('service')`. Full error is `DoesNotExist at /api/v1/organisation/provider/
Service matching query does not exist`. `File "/code/classification/serializers.py" in create
  117.         thisService = Service.objects.get(name=validated_data.get('service'))`